# R: how to plot with not very small numbers?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gmp, largenumber

I have a sample containing not very small numbers.

```
bits,N,cost,cycles,factor1,factor2,time
112,4128116717189377876765869867845141,88907974,1,59257226083494863,69664359775679707,228
122,2663989022657678986885885123100698459,325797907,1,1203233169388913363,2214025585756283993,1166
```

Is it possible for R to draw plots with such numbers?  I'd like to plot `cost` by `N`.  How would you handle this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need plot it directly. if all of the N is big number(Same order of magnitude), you should standardized  your data first.

E.g. normalization

for example:

```
normalization<-function(x){
    return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}
normalization(data)
```

Comment: I won't quite be able to do this in R because these numbers are not very small.  But I guess you're saying: use a library like GMP, normalize your data, then plot it.  Is that it?

Comment: you can use any R library you want, But I want to tell you that you should preprocessing your data before you analysis or plot it.